# How do I Json.decode a union type?

Tags: json, elm

I have a type defined like this inside `module Foo exposing (..)`:

```
type Foo
    = Bar
        { a : String
        , b : String
        }
    | Baz
        ...
```

Then I've tried to create a `Json Decoder` in a separate module to decode that type like this:

```
barDecoder : Decoder Bar
barDecoder =
    map2 Bar
        (field "a" string)
        (field "b" string)
```

The Elm compiler gives me an error on the `map2 Bar` line saying that type `Bar` is not found. The module that contains the decoder has `import Foo exposing (..)`. I also tried moving this function into the same module that contains the type definition and get the same error, so it doesn't have anything to do with being in a separate module.

I've tried changing it to `map2 Foo.Bar`, but that didn't work either.

What's the right way to decode a union type like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Foo` is the type. `Bar` is a constructor. The signature should be:

```
barDecoder : Decoder Foo
```

Furthermore, you will get a compile error on your current decoder. Let's add an alias for the contents of the record in `Bar`:

```
type alias BarContents =
    { a : String
    , b : String
    }

type Foo
    = Bar BarContents
    | Baz
```

Your decoder could then look like this:

```
barDecoder : Decoder Foo
barDecoder =
    Json.Decode.map Bar <|
         map2 BarContents
            (field "a" string)
            (field "b" string)
```

Answer (score 11):

You should use `Json.Decode.oneOf` if you have multiple way of decoding json.

Here is example how you can use it.
(I made up `Baz` because you did not specify it.)

```elm
import Json.Decode as Json

type Foo
    = Bar
        { a : String
        , b : String
        }
    | Baz Int


barDecoder : Json.Decoder Foo
barDecoder =
    Json.map2 (\x y -> Bar { a = x, b = y })
        (Json.field "a" Json.string)
        (Json.field "b" Json.string)


bazDecoder : Json.Decoder Foo
bazDecoder =
    Json.map Baz Json.int


fooDecoder : Json.Decoder Foo
fooDecoder =
    Json.oneOf [ barDecoder, bazDecoder ]
```

Comment: I am using `oneOf` as you show here, but that's not where the compiler error was, so I didn't include it in my question. Thanks!